# pass HashSet<Text> as Iterable<Text> in reduce function's parameter - HADOOP

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a HashMap and I want to pass its values to the reduce function in hadoop via overoloading the run method. The reduce function accepts Iterable. Is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what you have tried? and not getting what you want

Comment: How and from where are you getting the HashMap in the Reducer? Please provide more info

Comment: I have overloaded the run method in Reducer's class and I get all the keys and values and store them in a HashMap<Text,HashSet<Text>>. Then I process them and after all I want to pass these to the reducer function. The process I am doing is about merging some keys and as a result putting together its values.

Answer (score 2):

HashSet (as in post title) is already iterable. Just pass it.

If you're using a map as your post body says, you can pass whichever is appropriate:

```
yourMap.keySet(); // set of K
yourMap.valueSet(); // set of V
yourMap.entrySet(); //set of Map.Entry<K,V>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry pass it, as @hexafraction says, `HashSet` implements `Iterable`.

Most of the collections type implements `Iterable` like `List`, `Set`, `Vector`, and so on. But not `Map` implementation.